# How is frequent itemsets compared with item-based collaborative filtering in recommender systems?

Tags: data-mining

What is the difference between data mining approaches: frequent itemsets and item-based collaborative filtering in the area of recommender systems?

Answer (score 1):

I think by "frequent itemsets" you mean the association rules that you derive from counting frequent itemsets. They tell us:

*people who do (like, buy, etc.) X tend to do (...) Y.*

For this you only need "positive" information, i.e. people who liked/bought/did.
Say this is about movies, you only know who liked the movie, among the others you don't know whether they disliked it or didn't see it.

item-based CF, and other CF techniques are typically used when you have both positive and negative feedback, such as ratings 0 to 5. You then use this information to *predict unknown ratings*.

For item-based CF, you're trying to predict a person's rating on item Y, and you look how this person has rated other *similar* items, where "X is similar to Y" means that other people who have rated both X and Y have given them very similar ratings. The information you get is then:

*Your have previously liked similar items to Y, therefore we predict you'll like Y.*

User-based CF is perhaps closer to association rules, and you get:

*People similar to you have liked Y, therefore we predict you will like Y.*